# Dumping a read-only (select) database

Tags: backup, mysql

I need to download a database given to me with select-only permissions to import it at my localhost for editing.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

How about disabling authentication temporarily and doing a mysqldump?

```
service mysql restart --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables
mysqldump --all-databases --routines --triggers > MySQLData.sql
service mysql restart
```

Now, move the mysqldump file to your local machine and run this

```
mysql -uroot -p < MySQLData.sql
```

Give it a Try!